# React - Filter In Dropdown?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass up a variable with the child to parent component nuance in React. I'm very close on getting the filtering that I want, but there's two small problems:

1.) The filter function appears to be called in a "lazy" fashion. As in, when I type in the dropdown field, it'll ONLY pass what was PREVIOUSLY in the field before I changed it.

2.) It seems that I get matches, but nothing adds to the dropdown div and clear it like I would hope.

Here's the modal with the search dropdown filter:

```
class AssignModal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { usrSearch: '' };
        this.handleTextChange = this.handleTextChange.bind(this);
        this.handleFilter = this.handleFilter.bind(this);
    }

    handleTextChange(e) {
        this.setState({ usrSearch: e.target.value });
        this.handleFilter();
    }
    handleFilter(e) {
        const input = this.state.usrSearch.trim();
        if (!input) {
            return;
        }
        this.props.filterDrop({ input: input });
    }
    render() {

      return (
          <div class="modal fade" id="assignModal" role="dialog">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 style={{ color: 'red' }}><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>Assign</h4>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
              <form role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Assign to:</label>
                      <div class="dropdown">
                          <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" value={this.state.usrSearch} onChange={this.handleTextChange} />
                          <div id="userDropdown" class="dropdown-content">


                          </div>
                      </div>

                      <br />
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-success btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>Assign</button>
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Cancel</button>
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          </div>
      );
      }
    }
```

And here's the JavaScript function the value is supposed to pass up to (it does pass up, I'm just not getting HTML elements added/cleared like I'd like):

```
filterUsers(input) {
        var users = this.usersCollection.data;
        var userDrop = $("#userDropdown");
        var inputCheck = String(Object.values(input));
        var userNames = users.map(function (e) { return e.userName });
        var pos = userNames.indexOf(inputCheck);
        alert(userNames);
        for (var i = 0; i < userNames.length; i++) {
            if (userNames[i].indexOf(inputCheck) > -1) {
                userDrop.add("<p>Existing</p>");
                alert("Found user");
            }
            else {
                userDrop.empty();
                alert("Didn't find user: " + inputCheck);
            }
        }
    }
```

If this is totally not the way I should be doing this, let me know a better way. The idea is to populate the dropdown from the text search box with the users that have been matched in the filter to select.

Updated code after suggestions:

Ticket component

```
class Ticket extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { data: this.props.initialData };
        this.userState = { data: this.props.userData };
        this.usersCollection = { data: this.props.userDB };
        this.matchedUserNames = [];
        this.serverMsg = { data: this.props.serverMsg };
        this.serverMsgRst = { data: this.props.srvMsgRst };
        this.getUsername = this.getUsername.bind(this);
        this.isClosed = this.isClosed.bind(this);
        this.toJavaScriptDate = this.toJavaScriptDate.bind(this);
        this.handleLogSubmit = this.handleLogSubmit.bind(this);
        this.checkServerMessage = this.checkServerMessage.bind(this);
        this.showAssignModal = this.showAssignModal.bind(this);
        this.filterUsers = this.filterUsers.bind(this);
    }
    filterUsers(input) {
        var users = this.usersCollection.data;
        var inputCheck = String(Object.values(input));
        var userNames = users.map(function (e) { return e.userName });

        const matchedUserNames = []
        for (var i = 0; i < userNames.length; i++) {
            if (userNames[i].indexOf(inputCheck) > -1) {
                matchedUserNames.push(userNames[i])
            }
        }
        //alert(matchedUserNames);
        this.setState({ matchedUserNames });
    }
    render() {
        var centerStyle = { alignItems: 'center', };

        var closed = this.isClosed();
        var closeTime = this.state.data.closeTime;

        if (!this.state.data.apptConfirmItems || this.state.data.apptConfirmItems == 0) {
            return (

                <div class="queue">
                    <AssignModal filterDrop={this.filterUsers} matchedUserNames={this.matchedUserNames} />
                    <div style={{ textAlign: 'left' }}><p>Current Owner: {this.getUsername({ checkLog: this.state.data.userOwnerId })}<button style={{ marginLeft: '1%', display: 'inline' }} className="btn btn-info" id="assignTicket" onClick={this.showAssignModal}>Assign</button></p></div>
                    {closed}   
                    <table className="table">
                        <tbody style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <h1>Affirm Logs</h1>
                                    </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <h2>Summary: {this.state.data.summary}</h2>
                                    </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <h5>Description: <i>{this.state.data.description}</i></h5>
                                    </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <div><h3>No logs at this time!</h3></div>
                    <LogForm onLogSubmit={this.handleLogSubmit} />
                </div>
            );
        }
        else {
            return (
                <div className="queue">
                    <AssignModal filterDrop={this.filterUsers} matchedUserNames={this.matchedUserNames} />
                    <div style={{ textAlign: 'left' }}><p>Current Owner: {this.getUsername({ checkLog: this.state.data.userOwnerId })}<button style={{ marginLeft: '1%', display: 'inline' }} className="btn btn-info" id="assignTicket" onClick={this.showAssignModal}>Assign</button></p></div>
                    {closed}
                    <table className = "table">
                        <tbody style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <h1>Affirm Logs</h1>
                                    </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <h2>Summary: {this.state.data.summary}</h2>
                                    </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <h5>Description: <i>{this.state.data.description}</i></h5>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <LogList data={this.state.data.apptConfirmItems} checkUser={this.getUsername} renderDate={this.toJavaScriptDate} />
                    <LogForm onLogSubmit={this.handleLogSubmit} />
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

AssignModal component

```
class AssignModal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { usrSearch: '' };
        this.handleTextChange = this.handleTextChange.bind(this);
        this.handleFilter = this.handleFilter.bind(this);
    }
    handleTextChange(e) {
        this.setState({ usrSearch: e.target.value }, this.handleFilter);
    }
    handleFilter() {
        const input = this.state.usrSearch.trim();
        if (!input) {
            return;
        }
        this.props.filterDrop({ input: input });
    }
        render() {

            return (
                <div class="modal fade" id="assignModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 style={{ color: 'red' }}><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>Assign</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="usrname"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Assign to:</label>
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" value={this.state.usrSearch} onChange={this.handleTextChange} />
                                <div id="userDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                                    {this.props.matchedUserNames.map(userName => <p>Existing: {userName}</p>)}

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <br />
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-success btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>Assign</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Cancel</button>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you simplify the code? Indentation too deep just makes me quit reading...

Comment: @hackape sorry about that. Edited the post so you can see the React modal component and read it more easily.

Comment: I've not read your full question but if you're looking for dropdown then I suggest you to not create custom yourself there is many packages that help you to serve your purpose and one of the best package is : https://react-select.com/home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. The filter function appears to be called in a "lazy" fashion. As in, when I type in the dropdown field, it'll ONLY pass what was PREVIOUSLY in the field before I changed it.

Reason why you're parent always get the *previous* value, is because the way you call `handleFilter()` is a bit "early" in react's sense. See code comments:

```
handleTextChange(e) {
  // `setState` is async, you update `usrSearch` here
  this.setState({ usrSearch: e.target.value });
  this.handleFilter();
}
handleFilter(e) {  // <-- off topic, but `e` is not used, remove it.
  // but here, because it's async,
  // `this.state.usrSearch` is not up-to-date yet
  const input = this.state.usrSearch.trim();
  if (!input) {
    return;
  }
  this.props.filterDrop({ input: input });
}

// --- right way to call `handleFilter` ---

handleTextChange(e) {
  // `setState` can accept a callback function as 2nd argument
  // this ensures `handleFilter` is called only after `userSearch` is updated
  this.setState({ usrSearch: e.target.value }, this.handleFilter);
}
```

---

> 2. It seems that I get matches, but nothing adds to the dropdown div and clear it like I would hope.

Now in `filterUsers()`, you opt to use jQuery to do the update. Because the above async issue, here's what will happen:

1. `setState()` async-ly schedules a update to `usrSearch`, not happening yet
2. `handleFilter() -> filterUsers()` sync-ly update `#userDropdown`'s DOM (yes it did happened)
3. scheduled `setState()` now happens, so `usrSearch` gets updated and `AssignModal` re-renders
4. the re-render just overrides your jQuery DOM update back to emptiness

I'm not saying mixing jQuery with React is always wrong, but most of the time it is, if you don't understand React well enough.

---

> If this is totally not the way I should be doing this, let me know a better way.

If you use `this.setState({ usrSearch: e.target.value }, this.handleFilter)`, then because the async issue is fixed, problem No.2 should automatically go away. But it's not the optimal way to go.

Here's a better way:

```
// 1. instead of use jQuery to update DOM right away, you update "state"
filterUsers(input) {
  var users = this.usersCollection.data;
  var inputCheck = String(Object.values(input));
  var userNames = users.map(function (e) { return e.userName });
  var pos = userNames.indexOf(inputCheck);

  const matchedUserNames = []
  for (var i = 0; i < userNames.length; i++) {
    if (userNames[i].indexOf(inputCheck) > -1) {
        matchedUserNames.push(userNames[i])
    }
  }

  this.setState({ matchedUserNames })
}

// 2. then you pass the `matchedUserNames` to child `AssignModal`
<AssignModal matchedUserNames={this.state.matchedUserNames} /*...*/ />

// 3. in AssignModel's render, do the DOM update using React
<div id="userDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
  {this.props.matchedUserNames.map(userName => <p>Existing: {userName}</p>)}
</div>
```

Also, it's not a good idea to keep `usrSearch` as `AssignModel`'s state. Since your parent also read this value as in `filterUsers(input)`, you'd better keep in as the parent's state, then pass it as a prop to `AssignModel`. I'll leave this part to you.

Comment: Would I still be calling the filterUsers function from the AssignModal component in your answer?...

Comment: @KieranOjakangas I thought the filterUser fn is in parent, is it actually in AssignModal? You didn't show that part in your description

Comment: No it's in the parent of the whole JSX. I just thought I needed to call on it from the child for things to happen. That's why I don't see an alternative to the 'fix' you don't recommend - the calling of this.handleFilter on the same line as setting the state of 'usrSearch'

Comment: @KieranOjakangas I didn't get what you mean. I see you call `this.props.filtetDrop`, I assume `filterDrop` calls `filterUser`. So you did call `filterUser` indirectly, right? The what part you don't understand about my answer?

Comment: Yup, that's what I'm talking about.

Comment: I had to upvote your answer, it's just... slight problem. Currently I can enter characters but I don't see the drop down div update with a username. Further, it seems that when I click the "x" in the dropdown div, the letters I typed come back after a second. This to me indicates that something didn't get passed down right from the filter function...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191833/discussion-between-kieran-ojakangas-and-hackape).

Comment: Up to you if you have time to chat. I added updated code to my question per your suggestion. Let me know if and when you can why the children user elements don't get added to the dropdown div

Comment: I finally had to accept your answer. I was experiencing a different issue, which was trying to update a lone JavaScript var with setState instead of actually setting it in the state. But your suggestion outside of that different issue was super helpful - thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

@hackape I finally had to accept your answer. I was experiencing a different issue, which was trying to update a lone JavaScript var with setState instead of actually setting it in the state. But your suggestion outside of that different issue was super helpful - thanks so much!

Comment: I added this answer by mistake - if someone can remove it please do.